# Table name prefix for columns in UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, t-sql

Is table name prefix for fields to be update not allowed in `SQL`?  Like:

```
UPDATE tablename 
   SET tablename.mycolums = true 
 WHERE ...
```

What is the **SQL** standard?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting

Comment: I think he's looking for a cross-discipline explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not valid to prefix the column in the SET section with table alias in PostgreSQL, mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html):

> column
>
> The name of a column in table. The column name can be qualified with a subfield name or array subscript, if needed. Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE tab SET tab.col = 1 is invalid.

It is also mentioned that this behavior conforms to the SQL standard.

Answer (score 5):

The above query perfectly works in `SQL SERVER` environment.

The `SQL` standard for `UPDATE` statement has following form:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value [, column_name = value ...] [WHERE condition]
```

But Some databases uses non standard form by using FROM in `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE alias_name 
alias_name.mycolums=true
FROM tablename alias_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ofcourse it is allowed in Sql-Server. If you write a query like below, its working fine.

```
UPDATE KKDb SET KKDb.StdName = 'Sai' WHERE (KKDb.StdNo = 1)
```